# Convert a list of key value pairs to a hashtable

Tags: powershell

What is the best way to convert a List to a Hashtable?

Say I have a list like `("Key",$value,"Key2",$value2)`

What is the shortest syntax to convert it into a Hashtable?

Comment: It was easier in Perl, wasn't it? :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following

```
$table = new-object System.Collections.Hashtable
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $list.Length; $i += 2 ) {
  $table.Add($list[$i],$list[$i+1]);
}
```

Comment: I guess I was hoping for something a bit more terse

Answer (score 13):

```
Function ConvertTo-Hashtable($list) {
    $h = @{}

    while($list) {
        $head, $next, $list = $list
        $h.$head = $next
    }

    $h
}

ConvertTo-Hashtable ("Key",1,"Key2",2)
```

Comment: see also Bruce Payette's post: [PowerShell Tip: How to “shift” arrays…](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/02/06/powershell-tip-how-to-shift-arrays.aspx)

Comment: Yes. Plus this is a standard pattern in the functional world.

It can be shortened to 

 while($head, $next, $list = $list) {        
        $h.$head = $next
}

Comment: @EmperorXLII - updated link to Bruce Payette's post: [PowerShell Tip: How to “shift” arrays](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-tip-how-to-shift-arrays/)

Answer (score 7):

If your list is composed of [`NameValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.namevaluepair?view=azure-dotnet) objects, then you can use:

```
Function ConvertListOfNVPTo-Hashtable($list) {
    $h = @{}
    $list | ForEach-Object {
        $h[$_.Name] = $_.Value
    }
    return $h
}
```

Comment: Works with environment variables too: `$artifacts = gci env:* | Sort Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_*"};
$results = @{ artifacts = ConvertTo-Hashtable($artifacts) }
$results | ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$ht = @{}
$key = "";
("Key",5,"Key2",6) | foreach `
{  
    if($key)  
    {
        $ht.$key = $_; 
        $key=""; 
    } else 
    {$key=$_}   
}
```

Comment: I like that but you can simplify that a bit:
$ht = @{};$key = 0
"Key",5,"Key2",6 | foreach {if($key) {$ht.$key = $_;$key=0} else {$key=$_}}

Comment: No problem. I really like that you can set a hashtable entry using property syntax when the property name is a variable e.g. $ht.$key = $_.  That just strikes me as nifty.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$h = @{}  
0..($l.count - 1) | ? {$_ -band 1} | % {$h.Add($l[$_-1],$l[$_])}  

$h = @{}  
0..($l.count - 1) | ? {$_ -band 1} | % {$h.($l[$_-1]) = $l[$_]}  

$h = @{}  
$i = 0  
while ($i -lt $l.count) {$h.Add($l[$i++],$l[$i++])}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function Select-Hashtable {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
            [PSObject[]]$InputObject,
            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [string]$Property
       )
       begin { $hashtable = [Hashtable]::new() }
       process { $InputObject | %{ $hashtable[$_."$Property"] = $_} }
       end { $hashtable }
    }
```

then (a pointless example):

```
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Select-Hashtable -Property Name
    $documents = $items['Documents']
```