# How to create an associative array, preferably a one-liner?

Tags: powershell

I have this:

```
$str = "name = username`nemail = user@example.com"
```

Which is `LF` separated string, as part of an INI file. I want to create associative array so that for instance `$vars['name']` will return `'username'`. This is how I split it to lines:

```
$vars = ([regex]'\n').Split($str) | %{ $_.Trim() }
```

What change should I make to the line above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>If you are a lucky owner of Powershell 4 then</s> you can use `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet:

```powershell
$str = "name = username`nemail = user@example.com"
$vars = ConvertFrom-StringData $str
```

Result:

```powershell
PS C:\> $vars

Name                           Value
----                           -----
name                           username
email                          user@example.com
```

Comment: Great answer! Also, ConvertFrom-StringData is supposed to be available from PowerShell 3.0, as per [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900(v=wps.620).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

A more PoSh version of [PeterK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548983/1630171)'s answer would look like this:

```
$vars = @{}
$str.Trim() -split "\s*`n\s*" | % {
  $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*'
  $vars[$key] = $value
}
```

Using `$vars[$key] = $value` instead of `$vars.Add($key, $value)` avoids errors in case you have duplicate keys.

You could also split the string into an array of alternating key and value fields and then [fill the hashtable from that array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597901/1630171):

```
$vars = @{}
$list = $str.Trim() -split "\s*`n\s*" -split '\s*=\s*'
while ($list) {
  $key, $value, $list = $list
  $vars[$key] = $value
}
```

Each of the examples can be mangled into a single line by separating the statements with semicolons:

```
$vars = @{}; $str.Trim() -split "\s*`n\s*" | % { $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*'; $vars[$key] = $value }
```

```
$vars = @{}; $list = $str.Trim() -split "\s*`n\s*" -split '\s*=\s*'; while ($list) { $key, $value, $list = $list; $vars[$key] = $value }
```

Comment: I guess I can't deny I come from regular programmer background :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a one-liner, but one way to do it is:

```
$hashtable = @{};
$key_value_pairs = $str.Split("`n");
foreach($key_value in $key_value_pairs)
{
    $key_value_pair = $key_value.Split('=');
    $hashtable.Add($key_value_pair[0].Trim(), $key_value_pair[1].Trim());
}
```

The input string is first split into an array, each item containing a key-value pair in a single line. For each key-value pair, we split them into a 'key' and 'value' on "=", again into a regular array. Both the key and value are trimmed and added to the hash table. Once this is done, `$hashtable["name"]` will return *"username"* and `$hashtable["email"]` will return *"user@example.com"*